# Which charting libraries (gems) for ruby allow me to create scatter charts using time as the x axis?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, rubygems

So I love the (relatively new) `chartkick` gem for ruby -- its so stupid easy to use -- but it does not support scatter plots with time as the x axis. As it is, I'm stuck with charts of irregularly collected blood sugars in a line chart that look like this:

[image: blood sugar data]

Feel free to create your own account at bloodsugarcloud.com and start measurin!

Anyway, this data visualization is misleading in a line chart format because the format presumes a continuity in the readings which is anything but the case.

Have cracked open the `googlecharts` gem documentation and it does not appear at least at first to support this functionality either.

I know I risk falling on the sword as far as karma points go for asking this question (do your worst!) but would greatly appreciate some suggestions on ruby charting libraries to use. I can sort of do javascript, so perhaps I could pass in unix epoch timestamps (integers) as the x values and get javascript to reinterpret those in the x axis interval labels as dates? That seems drastic. Please advise.

EDIT: Some ideas

- perhaps I could use javascript to inform highcharts (which chartkick uses) to a.) create dots where each point is on the chart and b.) tell it NOT to connect the dots with lines. Also seems drastic.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com). There is a Ruby edition available.